# Debugging arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management() gives ERROR 000368: Invalid input data?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location, error-000368

When i trying to do Select by location i got :
arcgis scripting.
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation)

I am trying to excecute select by location on current selected feature after select by attribute.

```
env.workspace = "C:\temp"

input = 'C:\\temp\M0TASHT\M0TASHT.gdb\sLine'
input1= 'C:\\temp\M0TASHT\M0TASHT.gdb\sManhole'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('sManhole', 'sManhole_lyr')
in_features = 'sManhole_lyr'
where_clause = '"ManholeSubtype" = ('"4515" ')'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_features, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("C:\\temp\M0TASHT\M0TASHT.gdb\sLine", "INTERSECT", "sManhole_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

`"C:\\temp\M0TASHT\M0TASHT.gdb\sLine"`

you need to double all your back slashes to escape them i.e.

`"C:\\temp\\M0TASHT\\M0TASHT.gdb\\sLine"`

And instead of

> where_clause = '"ManholeSubtype" = ('"4515" ')'

Try

> where_clause =  ' "ManholeSubtype" = ' + " '4515' "

Or

> where_clause =  ' ' ' "ManholeSubtype" = 4515 ' ' '

Which will depend on whether the field is text or integer.